# How to dynamically return API JSON from the database and store JSON in MySQL in Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5.1

I am currently developing an api for my site to work with google maps. I have successfully developed an api with help from the community. But it only outputs a single page. I need it to be dynamic, because results will be based off of input from the user. As it stands my controller looks like this

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $results = [];

        foreach (Post::all() as $post)
        {
            $results[] = [
                'id' => $post->id,
                'marketname' => $post->subtitle,
            ];
        }

        return ['results' => $results];
    }
}
```

but this isn't dynamic.

I was thinking of copying my search and modifying it. it looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\TagIndexData;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use App\Video;
use App\Tag;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TagController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->get('q');

        $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
                ->orwhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

        $videos = Video::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orwhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();

            $tag = $request->get('tag');
            $data = $this->dispatch(new TagIndexData($tag));
            $layout = $tag ? Tag::layout($tag) : 'tags.layouts.index';

            return view($layout, $data)->withPosts($posts)->withVideos($videos);

    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to store json in mysql nor how to query it and output it Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To be clear on what I want. I want a person to enter their zipcode or address and then return a google map populated with markers indicating nearby events.

I am trying to modify a tutorial I did using a farmers market api mashed up with googles. Part of the javascript looks like this

```
 accessURL="http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=" + userZip/address;
```

where userZip/address is input that I want to use to populate the google map

any advice on how I should structure this is welcomed

Comment: Simply returning `Post:all()` in the controller method would return a JSON array of all products.

Comment: @JohnBupit thanks. I have never worked with json until recently. how would I store it? while tinkering around and posting on forums , I have read that it should be posted as one long string is this how it's done?

Comment: Why do you need to store it? Isn't all your data stored in a relational database?

Answer (score 1):

Returning JSON from the controller is pretty straight forward. Simply return the collection:

```
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::all();
    return $posts;
}
```

Or if you only need to return certain fields, use `select()`:

```
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::select(['id', 'subtitle as marketname'])->get();
    return $posts;
}
```